# How to piece together a simple flask web app

Tags: flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a small web app. A simple price scraper. I'm trying to piece it together into a web app without success.

Here's my working piece of python code I have, that returns the price of the specific item which is :
`918193-012`

Basically the idea is : a user would input a stock code of a product, and in return, on the same page/or the other page, he would receive the price for that product. Any advices are appreciated.

[image]

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess

url = f'https://www.tennis.fr/catalogsearch/result/?q=918193-012'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
capturedPrice = soup.findAll('p', class_="special-price")[0].text
capturedPrice = capturedPrice.strip('0')
capturedPrice = capturedPrice.strip()

print(capturedPrice[35:])
```

Here's my `app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

An here's: the `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" > 
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Find the best prices</h1>
<p><h4>Stock code to test: 918193-012</h3></p>
<form class="example" action="" style="margin:auto;max-width:500px">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Stock code" name="">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract Input-Information from your HTML Site. A possible solution would be to use a form:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask import render_template
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)

class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    input = StringField('Input',validators=[DataRequired()]
    submit = SubmitField('Search for Price')

@app.route('/')
def index():
   form = InputForm()
   if form.validate_on_submit():
      result = form.input.data
      return render_template("index.html", result=result, form=form)
   else:
      return render_template("index.html",form=form)


if __name__=="__main__":
      app.run(debug=True)
```

You can change the StringField to IntegerField if you want to, thats on you.
Next step would be to add sth to your @app.route:

Ofcourse you need to add some code to your HTML Site to pass the Search-Value to the Web App.

instead of your normal html button you need to pass the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  ##your css stuff## 
  <style>

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
    <h1>Find the best prices</h1>
    <p><h4>Stock code to test: 918193-012</h3></p>
    {{ form.input(class="form-control") }}
    {{ form.submit(class="btn") }}
    {% if result == #yourvalue# %}  
    #your printed data# 
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

in this example bootstrap is used for design but thats changable the way you want it
 I hope my text was understandable

Edit 1:

You use an if statement inside the html site if you want to use just one html file. With my example you pass the result to the html with the render_template line.

Comment: thank you, but I'm using already a form. Which is empty at the moment, 'because I don't really know how to connect it...  How wtf is better than the form I have inside my html code ? Thank you !

Comment: One Question: Where do you save your data? In a database or is it just an example application with one possible Search Result?

Comment: it's just one possible search result. no need to save it in a database or so... it's more of a building url from the form input, scrape the page, and display the result which should be a price : 110,50 € .  If that make sense to you.

Comment: yeah okay and it should be on one html page right? so not redirect to a search result page? You said you already usiing a form. But its empty. Why? If you already use a form, why not using it to get data from the Html page?

Comment: it could be on the same page or a result page, what is the easiest way of doing it ?

Comment: In your situation one page would be perfectly fine. Wait ill add some to my answer

Comment: Danke dir ! Liebe gruesse aus Baden !

Comment: Das kam unerwartet ! Aber ich bleibe bei Englisch unseren Mit-Usern zuliebe ;)

Comment: deal ! Let's crack this one !

Comment: What i kind of forgot: If you use your html file as template. You need to move it inside a folder named templates, so flask can find it.  What is your current Project structure?

Comment: My project structure app.py / templates / index.html that's basically it

Comment: would appreciate if you can also use my structure in your response, so I can follow it easier.  thanks

Comment: i'm getting an error on line 11 :     File "app.py", line 11
    submit = SubmitField('Search for Price')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: sorry my mistake. missing closing bracket at the line above. input = StringField('Input',validators=[DataRequired()])

Comment: alright, that is good. now when I check the http://127.0.0.1:5000/ I get an error : KeyError: 'A secret key is required to use CSRF.'  u know what it could be ?

Comment: figured that out ! sweet ! now I don't have a button on the page :(

Comment: HTML:
{{ form.submit(class="btn") }}
Instead of your html button

Comment: Ohh man...can you do me a favor and show the full index.html content like you did for the app.py ?

Comment: Thank you brother ! I get an error saying : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '#' at 1069 ! You are almost there ! I wish I can chat with you :(

Comment: Did you delete my ##comments ? And added your own code? maybe thats colliding with the Template Syntax

Comment: Hey Andi, no i did not delete the #comments. That could be a problem. What my part of the code would be in there than ?

Comment: "Ofcourse you need to add some code to your HTML Site to pass the Search-Value to the Web App" - this is the piece I'm missing now ! When you have some time, can you help me with that ? thanks !